# Inkscape landscape adds translate, why and can I turn it off?

Tags: svg, translate, inkscape

I am using Inkscape to make a template SVG which I extract out the rect coordinates to use for my own drawing program.

I've noticed that Inkscape, when in landscape mode, adds a translate(0,-308.2677) to the group g element and then each rectangle rect element has a corresponding translate(0,308.2677).

My guess is that this is added (in A4 mode 308 is 'height - width' in portrait) in order to move the origin from top left to bottom left.  So when a user of Inkscape swaps back and forth from landscape and portrait the bottom left is fixed with all items relative to that.

To me this seems a bit strange as Inkscape is an SVG tool and coords in SVG are top left growing x to the right, and y down.

My question is can I turn this off to force Inkscape to keep the origin at top left and not to dirty the SVG with extra translates?

Bonus: why does Inkscape do this?  It is just aesthetics with the assumption that most people are Cartesian or is there a good programming reason for this?

thanks,

LB

Answer (score 0):

> is there a good programming reason for this

No. Not really. It dates back to the very early days of computer graphics and memory-mapped screen buffers.  (0,0) was at the top left because that was the lowest memory location.

As time went on, that became the default origin position for most (but not all) computer OSs and graphics formats.  And I am confident that was why the original SVG authors choose that arrangement also.

I suspect, as you do, that the Inkscape authors probably chose the normal cartesian bottom-left position because they though that would be more familiar to users.  They are not unique among vector editing software.